# Web service on IIS 7.5 suddenly ceases to work

Tags: c#, .net, windows, web-services, iis-7.5

I have developed a SOAP Service on basis of C# and .NET 4.0 (`service.dll`). The service internally loads a C++ DLL (`cpp.dll`) and does stuff. I deployed that on an IIS 7.5 running on Windows 7 and it all worked well. However, recently the service stopped working.

If I now try to create a service using the `wcftestclient` application shipped with Visual Studio, I get following error message:

> Warning: There were errors loading types in an assembly loaded from
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll'
>   some types in the assembly could not be loaded and will not be
>   available to the tool.Error: An error occurred in the tool.Error:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I did not touch *any* of the DLLs or so. Googling the error message didn't lead me anywhere, so I'm desperate now and would appreciate some help with this. What does the message mean and what should I investigate?

I can open http://myserver/myservice/service.svc?wsdl and it shows me the correct WSDL. Also, I have a command line tool which itself loads the `cpp.dll` and this works too, so the problem cannot be there. It has to be something with the `service.dll` or with the settings in IIS or with a recent Windows update screwing up my .NET environment... right?

Comment: still have no solution for this - meanwhile I setup the whole vm from scratch and that helped, so clearly something was wrong, but what?

Comment: Any update on this?